# Saber el valor de una celda y modificar sus estilos según su valor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tomando la siguiente tabla como ejemplo

```
columna 1 columna 2 columna 3
    10        8         9
     8        9         8
    10       10         8
```

Necesito que las celdas que contengan valor de 8 esten de color rojo
Como aquí

```css
.valor{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover" id="tabla">
     <thead class="bg-dark text-white text-center">
      <tr>
       <td>columna 1</td>
       <td>columna 2</td>
       <td>columna 3</td>
       <td>columna 4</td>
       <td>columna 5</td>
       <td>columna 6</td>
       <td>columna 7</td>
       <td>columna 8</td>
       <td>columna 9</td>
       <td>columna 10</td>
      </tr>      
     </thead>     
     <tbody class="text-center">
      <tr>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">9</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">9</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">9</td>
       <td class="">9</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">9</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">9</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">9</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
      </tr>

     </tbody>
    </table>
```

En el ejemplo anterior a las celdas con valor 8 le agrego la clase valor y con css le agrego el color rojo, pero necesito hacerlo con java script o jQuery.

```
columnas = $('.valor').text();

for(var i =0; i < columnas.length; i++){
    if(columnas[i] == 8){
        columnas[i].css('color','red');
    }
}
```

Utilizando jQuery a una variable llamada **columnas** le paso todas las celdas y su valor mediante el selector de clase 'valor' esto me funciona trato de recorrer con un for y para cada posición pregunto si el valor es igual con 8, hasta aquí no tengo problema al parecer funciona correctamente, la situación es cuando quiero añadirle los estilos a la celda en la posición **n** me arroja el siguiente error:

**Uncaught TypeError: columnas[i].text is not a function**

### por lo que solicito su ayuda, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que seleccionar primero los `td` con clase `valor`, después lo recorres con un `for` y para obtener su contenido puedes utilizar `innerHTML`, después validas si el contenido es **8**, le agregas el color con `style.color="red"`, no hay necesidad de usar `jQuery`, con `JavaScript` puro funciona.

```js
let td = document.getElementsByClassName('valor');

for(let i = 0; i < td.length; i++){
  
    //console.log(td[i].innerHTML);
    
      //console.log(td[i]);
    
   if(td[i].innerHTML == '8'){
    
        td[i].style.color = 'red';
        
    }

}
```

```css
/*.valor{
  color:red;
}*/
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover" id="tabla">
     <thead class="bg-dark text-white text-center">
      <tr>
       <td>columna 1</td>
       <td>columna 2</td>
       <td>columna 3</td>
       <td>columna 4</td>
       <td>columna 5</td>
       <td>columna 6</td>
       <td>columna 7</td>
       <td>columna 8</td>
       <td>columna 9</td>
       <td>columna 10</td>
      </tr>      
     </thead>     
     <tbody class="text-center">
      <tr>
       <td class="valor">10</td>
       <td class="valor">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">9</td>
       <td class="valor">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">10</td>
       <td class="valor">10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">9</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">9</td>
       <td class="">9</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">9</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">9</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">9</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
       <td class="">10</td>
       <td class="valor">8</td>
      </tr>

     </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: He utilizado lo que propones pero se cambia el color de todas las celdas incluso las que no tienes el valor de 8, cable aclarar que en mi ejemplo la clase valor solo aplicaba para las celdas de valor 8 esto lo hice para poder colorearlas con css, pero en realidad todas las celdas tienen asignada esta clase.

Comment: Listo, puedes verificar la respuesta, ya la edité y funciona como pretendes.

Comment: Correcto veo que hiciste varias ediciones, fui probando una por una y no funcionaba pienso que era por que usabas jQuery y javascript puro me ha pasado algunas veces, usando la ultima modificación que hiciste con js puro funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: No hay de que compañero un gusto poder ayudarte! :)

Answer (score 2):

el problema es que al hacer `columnas = $('.valor').text();` estas obteniendo un arreglo de string con los valores de los td lo que tienes que hacer es obtener como tal el objeto y no el texto `columnas = $('.valor')` y hacer las adecuaciones dentro del for.

```
columnas = $('.valor');

for (var i = 0; i < columnas.length; i++) {
  if (columnas[i].innerHTML == '8') {
   columnas[i].style.color = 'red';
  }
}
```

o igual puedes hacer que se recorra todas los `<td>` de la tabla para que agregue la condición.

```
$("#tabla tbody tr td").each(function (element) {
   if ($(this).text() == 8) {
       $(this).css('color', 'red');
   }
});
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo el mismo problema pero la diferencia es que necesito una funcion para cambiar el color de fondo de la td className "celda" de acuerdo al dato de estadotk, cuando el dato sea Pendiente el color de fondo debe ser rojo, me podrian ayudar por favor...

ListadoTickets.map((ticket) => (

```
                                <tr key={ticket._id}>
                                    <td >{ticket.fecha}</td>
                                    <td>{ticket.asunto}</td>
                                    <td class="overflow-auto col-md-2 "> 
                                    {ticket.solicitud}</td>
                                    <td >{ticket.agente}</td>
                                    <td  className='celda'> {ticket.estadotk } 
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="overflow-auto col-md-2 "> 
                                    {ticket.cierre}</td>
                                    <td>{ticket.fechaCierre}</td>
                                    <td>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                            ))
```

Comment: Hola Luis, bienvenido, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines este comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos, puedes abrir una nueva pregunta con tus inquietudes, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta.

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/375894)